# Fail to catch Exception

Tags: java, exception, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, svnkit

I'm using SVNKit and the only way I found out to test Authentification to the server is by using method `testConnection()` of class `SVNRepository`.

The method doesn't return a boolean but throws an Exception.

```
public abstract void testConnection()
                         throws SVNException
```

The problem is that, instead of being catch, I get a coldfusion error :
[image: coldfusion error in try catch (SVNRepository.testConnection())]

Here is my code:

```
        clientManager = CreateObject("java", "org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNClientManager").newInstance();

        authManagerJO = CreateObject("java", "org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil").
                createDefaultAuthenticationManager(ARGUMENTS.username, JavaCast("String", ARGUMENTS.password));
        authManagerJO.setAuthenticationForced(true);
        clientManager.setAuthenticationManager(authManagerJO); 
        svnDavRepoFactory = CreateObject("java", "org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepositoryFactory").setup();
        repositoryUrlJO = CreateObject("java", "org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL").parseURIDecoded(APPLICATION.svn_repository_audifiles);
        svnRepository = clientManager.createRepository(repositoryUrlJO, true);
        try{
            svnRepository.testConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            svnRepository = "";
        }
```

Comment: Note: if login succeeds, the method doesn't fail. Only fails when exception is thrown (wrong username/password).

Comment: Does it also happens when you use `catch( Throwable e )` ?

Comment: @Robin `catch (Throwable e)` also fails.

Comment: @FrancisP: That claims to be in "SVNKitHelper.cfc" - so is this not normal Java? I hadn't spotted that before. Perhaps that's the key...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: no it's a java object used by a ColdFusion component. Perhaps, maybe the `try..catch` syntax is not valid within my `<cfscript>` tag.

Comment: Are you testing this with an empty username? If so, does it occur with a legal (but possibly unregistered) username?

Comment: The username is not empty. The goal is to test every cases of login failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try catching `Any` instead of `Exception` ?

This way, you will be sure to catch *everything*, even if the exception is not an `Exception` like Jon proposed.

Comment: Worked! `Exception` is not a recognized ColdFusion type. `Any` is the type used for objects.

Answer (score 7):

Well, it's entirely possible that it's throwing an exception which isn't an `Exception` - another kind of `Throwable`. You *could* catch `Throwable`, although that would be pretty harsh... catching it once, logging the exact exception type and then catching *that* would be reasonable though...

Comment: Alternately, you could check the API and find out exactly what kind of Throwable it throws, and catch that (or those).

Comment: @jpm: Assuming it's documented, of course - which it may not be, if it's an unchecked exception...

Comment: I would assume a method for testing a connection (and doesn't return a boolean) would have the only thing making it useful documented. Then again, I am a bit of an optimist.

Comment: @jpm: I'd have hoped they'd use *either* a checked exception *or* a subclass of RuntimeException, but apparently that's not the case...

Comment: according to the documentation, it does throw an `SVNException` which `extends Exception`. (http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html#testConnection%28%29)

Comment: @FrancisP - I know you fixed it using `any`, but out of curiosity did you try specifying the full path in the catch clause instead of just `Exception` or `SVNException`?

Comment: @Leigh: What do you mean by *full path* ?

Comment: @FrancisP - The full path to the exception class, like `org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException` or `java.lang.Exception`

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
catch (any e) {
    write dump(e);
    abort;
}
```

Then you'll see the actual error.